# Is the derivative of Inverse hyperbolic tan and cotan function the same??

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I was just having some trouble with the derivatives of Inverse Hyperbolic function,, especially the Tan hyperbolic inverse and the Cotan hyperbolic inverse, they both have the same derivative but their graphs are different.
And i was thinking, how can functions having different graphs have the same derivatives?

Sorry for, me being a bit dumb, in-case....

REGARDS!!

Comment: which functions do you use?

Comment: The functions are not defined on the same domain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#Inverse_hyperbolic_tangent

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I used tanh-1(x)  and cotanh-1(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hint

We have $\operatorname{arctanh}(0)=0$ and $\operatorname{arccoth}(0)$ doesn't exist, so they cannot have the same derivative.

Comment: So this means that than-1(x) exist on a domain where cotan-1(x) does not exist and vice versa. Now it makes sense.. Thanks @ Abdallah Hamman..